# Loop not working for sql update statement (mysqldb)

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, mysql-python, glob

I have a folder called 'testfolder' that includes two files -- 'Sigurdlogfile' and '2004ADlogfile'. Each file has a list of strings called `entries`. I need to run my code on both of them and am using `glob` to do this. My code creates a dictionary for each file and stores data extracted using regex where the dictionary keys are stored in `commonterms` below. Then it inserts each dictionary into a mysql table. It does all of this successfully, but my second sql statement is not inserting how it should (per file).

```
import glob
import re
files = glob.glob('/home/user/testfolder/*logfile*')

commonterms = (["freq", "\s?(\d+e?\d*)\s?"],
               ["tx", "#txpattern"],
               ["rx", "#rxpattern"], ...)

terms = [commonterms[i][0] for i in range(len(commonterms))]
patterns = [commonterms[i][1] for i in range(len(commonterms))]

def getTerms(entry):
    for i in range(len(terms)):
        term = re.search(patterns[i], entry)
        if term:
            term = term.groups()[0] if term.groups()[0] is not None else term.groups()[1]
        else:
            term = 'NULL'
        d[terms[i]] += [term]
    return d

for filename in files:
    #code to create 'entries'
    objkey = re.match(r'/home/user/testfolder/(.+?)logfile', filename).group(1)

    d = {t: [] for t in terms}

    for entry in entries:
        d = getTerms(entry)

    import MySQLdb
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='', user='', passwd='', db='')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cols = d.keys()
    vals = d.values()

    for i in range(len(entries)):
        lst = [item[i] for item in vals]
        csv = "'{}'".format("','".join(lst))
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s);" % (','.join(cols), csv.replace("'NULL'", "NULL"))
        cursor.execute(sql1)

#now in my 2nd sql statement I need to update the table with data from an old table, which is where I have the problem...

    sql2 = "UPDATE table, oldtable SET table.key1 = oldtable.key1, 
table.key2 = oldtable.key2 WHERE oldtable.obj = %s;" % repr(objkey)
    cursor.execute(sql2)

    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

The problem is that in the second sql statement, it ends up inserting that data into all columns of the table from only one of the `objkey`s, but I need it to insert different data depending on which file the code is currently running on. I can't figure out why this is, since I've defined `objkey` inside my `for filename in files` loop. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your second query doesn't have any relation between `table` and `oldtable`, so it's doing a full cross product.

Comment: You should learn to do prepared statements instead of doing string substitution.

Comment: @Barmar How do you mean? It's inserting the correct data for 'Sigurdlogfile' from the old table, but the problem is that it's also inserting that Sigurd data where it should be inserting from 2004AD

Comment: You have no conditions on which rows in `table` to update, only which row in `oldtable` to copy from. So the first iteration of the loop updates all rows from one file, then the second iteration updates all the rows from the other file.

Comment: So all of the first updates are overwritten by the second update.

Comment: I see. How would I add this additional condition then? I do want it to update all rows in each respective file, actually. But instead of overwriting, I'd like the second update to just add in the data to the new rows for that file's loop.

Comment: You need something in the `WHERE` clause that identifies those rows. Or you could do as part of the `INSERT`, using `INSERT INTO table(key1, key2, ...) SELECT key1, key2, ... FROM oldtable WHERE obj = %s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, do them together to incorporate the fields from the old table.

```
for i in range(len(entries)):
    lst = [item[i] for item in vals]
    csv = "'{}'".format("','".join(lst))
    sql1 = """INSERT INTO table (key1, key2, %s) 
            SELECT o.key1, o.key2, a.*
            FROM (SELECT %s) AS a
            LEFT JOIN oldtable AS o ON o.obj = %s""" % (','.join(cols), csv.replace("'NULL'", "NULL"), repr(objkey))
    cursor.execute(sql1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue of overwriting. However I'm running into something else now -- sometimes a particular file does not have any data in the old table (so if I run the command 'select * from oldtable where obj = 'some object'', it returns an empty set). And in this case it skips over it and doesn't enter in any of the data, even from the dictionary. But how would I still get the other data to be inserted and those key1 and key2 fields just be kept as 'NULL'?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do this with a `LEFT JOIN`.